# register_theme_directory() not working from mu-plugin

Tags: add-theme-support, mu-plugins

I have a must use plugin that uses register_theme_directory() but no matter what path I pass in, it always returns false.

For some background I am using domain based database switching in the wp-config to manage multiple distinct sites with one install, (i am not using a network install because each site needs it own unique users database).  I have some themes I want to only be available to one specific site, so I put it in a special directory and try to register the theme directory in a mu-plugin if the domain is accessed.

Here is the relevant portion of my directory-structure:

```
wp-content
 |-> site-themes
      |-> site-a
           |-> theme-1
           |-> theme-2
```

I have tried the following:

```
if ( [check site domain ] ) {
    register_theme_directory( '[wordpress root]/wp-content/site-themes/site-a' );
}
```

When that didn't work I figured it must need each theme to have its directory registered so I tried this:

```
if ( [check site domain ] ) {
    register_theme_directory( '[wordpress root]/wp-content/site-themes/site-a/theme-1' );
    register_theme_directory( '[wordpress root]/wp-content/site-themes/site-a/theme-2' );
}
```

But that didn't work either. I am sure I am missing something simple. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it returns `false`, then it's very likely because the directory does not exist. And you can also try using a path relative to `wp-content` - `register_theme_directory( 'site-themes/site-a' )`

Comment: Have you verified that whatever you're using for `[check site domain ]` is working?

Comment: And try `echo 'my conditional check is ok';` before your `register_theme_directory()` call to confirm your conditional is not actually the one that returned `false`.

Comment: Yes I use `strtolower( stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) )` for the conditional check just like I do in wp-config and also I echoed the result of `register_theme_directory()` to see that it was executing and it was returning false.  And the folder does exist so I see no reason why this doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, I feel stupid. After trying to check `file_exists()` for a sanity check I saw that the directory did in fact not exist, confusingly at first until I realized that the directory did not exist because wp-content was listed in my .gitignore so when I committed it to deploy to my server the directory was removed.